# Disabling an automatic post generation with aggregated images posted to album

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios5, ios4

I am building an iOS application which is using Facebook API. I found that when I am posting a new image to album (using Graph API) Facebook create a new post itself with aggregated (summary) images posted to this album that day (post like: ***Name Surname*** added **X** new photos to the album **AlbumName**.).

**Is there any way to disable (or hide) creation of this post?** What I exactly want to achieve is  that I want to upload an image to application album silently and after create wall post with this image with specified message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for answer in Facebook Graph API docs in *Photos* section and that is why I didn't found it.

Answer was in *User* section in *photos* part ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos ).
While posting photo using Graph API to "me/photos" I only had to add parameter **no_story** with value **1**.